# if $U\cup W=V$ then $U=V$ or $W=V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $U,W$ two subspaces in $V$. Assuming that $U\cup W = V$, show that: $U=V$ or $W=V$.

So, by definition of union:
$$U \cup W = \left\{ {u + w|u \in U,w \in W} \right\}$$

- How to proceed?
- And a technical issue: Is $U \cup W$ equivalent to $U + W$?

EDIT:

---

Consider the following scenario (Following @Learner approach):
$U = V \backslash \{x\}$ and $W = V \backslash \{y\}$.

$U\cup W = V$, but none of the subspaces is equal to $V$.

Where is the error?

Comment: The definition of union should read $U \cup W = \{v| v \in U \text{ or } v \in W\}$. One important point of the exercise is precisely that $U \cup W$ is not equivalent to $U + W$: notice that if $V$ is a space with inner product, $U + U^\perp = V$

Comment: Your definition of $U \cup W$ is wrong; in fact $U \cup W := \{v \in V | v \in U \text{ or } v \in W\}$. What you define is $U + W$.

Comment: Maybe, But I have a specific question which stayed open. @nik

Comment: @SuperStamp: $U$ and $V$ aren't vector subspaces in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show more generally that $U\cup W$ can only be a vector space if one of $U,W$ is contained in the other, in which case the union is of course the latter (larger) of the two subspaces. To prove this, suppose to the contrary that neither of $U,W$ is contained in the other; choose $u\in U\setminus W$ and $w\in W\setminus U$, and prove that $u+w\notin U\cup W$ for a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $U \subsetneq V$ and $W \subsetneq V$, then $U \cup W \subsetneq V$.

Comment: But why there's no possibility that $U\cup W = V$?  
for example $U = V \backslash \{x\}$ and $W = V \backslash \{y\}$.

Comment: This is exactly what the guy wants to prove!!!